# Converting epoch time to string with specific format

Tags: python-3.x, xlrd

I am using python to read some data from .xls file and then automatically fill out a form online that requires specific formatting and I am stumbling with epoch time.

On my xls sheet I have date value 15/06/18. Desired output should be 150618.

I use `xlrd` to read the file and code as follows:

```
import xlrd
r_file = xlrd.open_workbook('test.xls')
r_sheet= r_file.sheet_by_index(0)
date = r_sheet.cell(0,0).value
```

this returns a float value of 43266.0 
How can I get a string in `ddmmyy` format without separators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel stores dates as days since Jan 1, 1900. However, Excel has an off-by-one error due to treating 1900 as a leap year, when in reality it's not.

```
import pandas as pd
date = 43266.0
if date <= 59:
    date -= 1
elif date == 60:
    raise ValueError("Feb 29, 1900 is not a real date!")
else:
    date -= 2
py_date = pd.to_datetime('1900-1-1') + pd.Timedelta(days=date)
py_date_str = py_date.strftime('%d%m%y')
print(py_date_str)  # 180617, aka June 17, 2018
```

Comment: This looks promising but it is 2 days off for some reason, 43266 is 15/06/18 in xls format.

Comment: Ah, yes. The number 1 corresponds to Jan 1, 1900, which means we need to subtract 1 from `date`, hence an off by one error... but it also seems that Excel and Python disagree on whether 1900 was a leap year. Excel says yes, Python says no. The correct answer is that 1900 was not a leap year. I guess that's something you have to deal with when using Excel.

Answer (score 0):

date.replace("/","")  should do the job.

```
import datetime 
date_tuple = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(date, r_file.datemode))
```

Comment: date.replace on what? I am getting a float number from xls.

Comment: import datetime
date_tuple = datetime.datetime(*xlrd.xldate_as_tuple(date, r_file.datemode))